# User defined input in a macro

Tags: imagej-macro

I am trying to create a macro on Fiji (ImageJ). I cannot find how to introduce a user input. I want to sum a stack with z project. Each sum is the result of 10 stacks. But the start is not the same. It varies between 1 and 11. So it would be fine when the user choose a startpoint. when the file is saved, the filename should contain the start and endpoint. So I know some weeks later which stacks I used. Thanks for some hints!

```
imageTitle=getTitle();
path = "D:/test/";
first = Dialog.getChoice();
// first = 8;
last = first+9;
selectWindow(imageTitle);
run("Z Project...", "start=first stop=last projection=[Sum Slices]");
run("Red");
saveAs("Tiff", path+"SUM_"+imageTitle+"("+first+last+")";
```

I get the error message:

> "No dialog created with Dialog.create() in line 3: 
>   first = Dialog.getChoice> () ;

When I didnt choose the start I get the error message:

> " ')' expected in line 9: 
>   saveAs ( "Tiff" , path + "SUM_" + imageTitle + "(" + first + last + ")" <;>

Comment: I modified my code a bit and now it works. I changed line 4 to first = getNumber("first?", 8); and the last line to: part1 = "("+first;
saveAs("Tiff", path+"SUM_"+imageTitle+part1+last+")");